# How do I convert a memory address 0x8134597 to "\x97\x45\x13\x08"

Tags: hex, endianness

I'm going through the PWK course where this springs up in the notes:

```
0x08134597 - > \x97\x45\x13\x08
```

What is the conversion between the two? The left being hex and the right being whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

simply reverse the string to

\x97\x45\x13\x08\